# NGINX: Proxy to blog on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, proxypass

I have a wordpress based site with blog in /blog location. I wanted to re-use this blog from an other site, but I am redirected to www.example.com. My nginx config of the location is:

```
location ~ ^/blog {
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  proxy_pass https://www.example.com$request_uri;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

How should this config look like?

Answer (score 0):

To make WordPress respond correctly to two different hostnames, you will need to make it hostname agnostic.

Change the WordPress configuration so that the hostname is not part of the HOME and SITEURL parameter values. For example, use a value `/blog`, instead of `https://www.example.com/blog`.

See [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for more.

---

Regarding the `location` block. It can be simplified as follow:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```